# Battery connection

Tags: boat

I screwed up and touched negative cable to positive on battery and it sparked and now when connected correctly no juice anywhere. Should there be a fuse somewhere?

Comment: There will be fuses.  One or more may well have blown.  You will need to provide more information about the car if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, on a boat, the main connection from the battery goes to the starter without a fuse. The main switch will cut this connection.

The main fuse that protects the circuitry from a short is usually after the starter. On many engines this is a push reset circuit breaker. It could also be a 90 amp fuse attached directly to the starter.

[image: Wiring diagram]